# Not able to perform a PDO Prepare Statement

Tags: php, pdo, odbc, visual-foxpro, dbase

'm trying to execute the following code:

```
try 
{
    $conn = new PDO('odbc:Clasges5');           
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO codpais (clapai,codpas,nompas) VALUES (:clapai,:codpas,:nompas)";
    $q = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $clapai = 31;
    $codpas = 'test codpas';
    $nompas = 'test nompas';
    $q->bindParam(':clapai', $clapai, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $q->bindParam(':codpas', $codpas, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $q->bindParam(':nompas', $nompas, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $q->execute();        
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

The database (VisualFox DBase via ODBC) looks like this:
- table codpais
- clapai primary key
- codpas string
- nompas string

I'm getting the error  Invalid character value for cast specification: 302

The problem is the "clapai". If i perform an update with codpas or nompas everything works OK, if i try tu update the clapai value it throws the same error.

Any tips to fix that? BTW. It's better to use the named placeholders or the question marks? any advantage?

Comment: named parameters are preferable in large queries. For your simple one with only 3 parameters, it's easy to count `?` positions. But consider how insanely ugly it would be to handle a query with 50+ `?` spread out all over. Named parameters at least have the advantage of being easily locatable.

Comment: Is `codpais` autoincremental ?

Comment: It should but i don't know if VisualFoxPro works with autoincremental. If i try to insert without the PK (clapai) i get the followin exception: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 581 [Microsoft][ODBC Visual FoxPro Driver]Field CLAPAI does not accept null values. So i must add the clapai field. If i do this without a prepared statement works OK. The thing is that i need to escape my querys.

Comment: I can't even create a prepared statement with odbc functions instead of pdo.

Comment: VFP does have autoincrement fields, but you can't use the ODBC driver with a database that has such fields. The ODBC driver addresses VFP 6 (and earlier) format, and autoincrement fields were added in VFP 8. Any chance you could use the OLEDB driver instead? It can talk to any VFP tables.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried with AdoDB but works with the odbc on the background, so it's the same. OleDB needs AdoDb? I'm a little confused with ODBC, OleDB & AdoDB. The VisualFoxPro Version Indeed is the 9.

Comment: I was trying to use the OLE DB Provider for VisualFoxPro, but, again, i have problems. The Driver is only for 32bit Systems and my client and server are both 64 bit, so, the data provider doesn't appear on my list.