# Bind SQL Server to VisualFoxPro Database

Tags: php, sql-server, visual-foxpro

As i am having tons of issues trying to work with ODBC for several weeks, like this one ([Not able to perform a PDO Prepare Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18498012/not-able-to-perform-a-pdo-prepare-statement?noredirect=1#comment27207675_18498012)) i was looking for another solution.

I found that i can bind a VisualFoxPro database to a SQLServer. I have no idea about SQLServer so before i put my hands on learning some SQLServer i have a few questions about this.

If i bind a VisualFoxPro database to SQLServer can i INSERT data to SQL Server and it will be added to VisualFoxPro... or will only work to retrieve data?

maybe this way i could create prepared statements and transactions?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can "upsize" foxpro tables to SQL which will duplicate the functionality of a Visual FoxPro database as closely as possible. You can also redirect Visual FoxPro views so that they use the newly created remote data instead of local data. With that being said, it is a pretty complex process (at least in my opinion), and depending on the size of your tables can take quite a while. You can read up on it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kh94s56z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czskh2h3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for starters.
I would suggest giving OLEDB drivers another look for your issue before you try to convert databases.

Chris